# VBA Macro - Copy Data

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I am working on pulling data from cells in Sheet1 to Sheet2 and I have the correct Macro for the data copy, however, I need to have specific entries pulled based on information in another cell.

I am starting on cell A14 for my code and all of the work will be done in column A.  Basically, I need to start at cell A14 in Sheet1 and pull every 5th cell and copy it into Sheet2 based on criteria found two cells below the cell I am determining if I need to copy or not.  The criteria of whether or not to copy the data from 2 cells above is if the cell contains "Choose an answer" or not.

For example,
x+5=n
If n+2="Choose and answer", copy n to Sheet2

The macro I have currently can be found below.

```
Sub CopyNthData()
Dim i As Long, icount As Long
Dim ilastrow As Long
Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet

Set wsFrom = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsTo = Sheets("Sheet2")
ilastrow = wsFrom.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
icount = 1

For i = 14 To ilastrow Step 5
    wsTo.Range("A" & icount) = wsFrom.Range("A" & i)
    icount = icount + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

[Image of Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwl7M.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

The principle is to use Offset. You can use it for the range to compare and the range to retrieve if required.

Given uncertainty of your comparison it seems

```
wsFrom.Cells(i, 1).Offset(2, 0)) = "choose an answer"
```

Compares two rows above current, whereas

```
wsFrom.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-2, 0)) = "choose an answer"
```

Compares two rows below

If you then want to copy something other than current cell, you can Offset from current cell e.g.

```
wsTo.Range("A" & icount) = wsFrom.Range("A" & i).Offset(1,0)
```

Example above, you then copy the value from the cell above the current.

In Offset the first number is the number of rows to move from current position and the second is the number of columns.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyNthData()

    Dim i As Long, icount As Long
    Dim ilastrow As Long
    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet

    Set wsFrom = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsTo = Sheets("Sheet2")

    ilastrow = wsFrom.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    icount = 1

    For i = 14 To ilastrow Step 5

         If LCase$(Trim$(wsFrom.Cells(i, 1).Offset(2, 0))) = "choose an answer" Then
            wsTo.Range("A" & icount) = wsFrom.Range("A" & i)
            icount = icount + 1
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What does doesn't work mean? Did you get an error message?

Comment: So I think there is some confusion, maybe that was just my fault in explaining.

Comment: I added an image link to show the data I'm looking at in my original post.  The criteria I'm looking at is two cells below what I want to copy over.

Comment: Instead of looking back 2, I should be looking forward 2.  The question original wording is correct.  I say it should look below 2 and then copy the data from 2 above if the criteria is met.

Comment: So you are looking 2 rows ahead of current row and copying current cell if two ahead says "choose..." ?

Comment: Correct.  Alright, so I got one of the items to copy over, but not others throughout the sheet.  There is data in cells 3366, 3401, 3416, etc that isn't copying over.  Not sure why it won't copy that over.

Comment: Everything in the code looks fine.  I've checked the items and Trim is unnecessary as there is no white space at the start or end of the string.  Just not really sure what else I can do.  I'm literally using the same exact code you are.

Comment: Solved it. The problem is the location of your counter variable.   icount = icount + 1. I have edited answer.